# Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll not found error at build

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I have issues while building a UnitTest project using C# from VS 2017

I have the following Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll assemblies on machine

C:>dir /s Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 3DA9-D3C3

Directory of C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow

05/09/2018  11:35 AM            98,864 Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll
               1 File(s)         98,864 bytes

Directory of C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\x64

05/09/2018  11:35 AM            98,864 Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll
               1 File(s)         98,864 bytes

Directory of C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\Extensions\TestPlatform

05/29/2018  04:22 PM            89,744 Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll
               1 File(s)         89,744 bytes

Directory of C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies

05/09/2018  11:35 AM            98,856 Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll
               1 File(s)         98,856 bytes

Directory of C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v2.0

05/09/2018  11:35 AM            86,848 Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll
               1 File(s)         86,848 bytes

Directory of C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v4.0

05/09/2018  11:35 AM            98,856 Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll
               1 File(s)         98,856 bytes

Directory of C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN.nuget\packages\microsoft.visualstudio.qualitytools.unittestframework.updated\15.0.26228\lib

06/18/2018  05:16 PM              Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll
               0 File(s)              0 bytes

Directory of C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN.nuget\packages\microsoft.visualstudio.qualitytools.unittestframework.updated\15.0.26228\lib\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll

06/13/2017  04:16 PM            98,440 Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll
               1 File(s)         98,440 bytes

```
 Total Files Listed:
           7 File(s)        670,472 bytes
           1 Dir(s)  43,857,920,000 bytes free
```

Errors are:

```
  Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
  Error     Error occurred during processing of assembly 'D:\code\tsm\tdp\agents\mmc\Fm.Common\bin_816\Release\Fm.Common.dll': Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.   Fm.Common.UnitTests         

  Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
  Error     The "BuildShadowTask" task failed unexpectedly.
  Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.Publicize.PublicizeException: Error occurred during processing of assembly 'D:\code\tsm\tdp\agents\mmc\Fm.Common\bin_816\Release\Fm.Common.dll': Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
     at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.Publicize.DynamicTypeEmitter.EmitAttachShadow()
     at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.Publicize.DynamicTypeEmitter..ctor(DynamicType type, ShadowerTargetType targetType)
     at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.Publicize.DynamicType..ctor(DynamicAssembly assembly, TypeBuilder outerType, Type type, TypeCreatorDelegate TypeCreator, ShadowerTargetType targetType)
     at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.Publicize.DynamicAssembly.ShadowType(Type type)
     at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.Publicize.Shadower.ShadowAssemblyHelper(ShadowerOptions options)
     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
     at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.Publicize.Shadower.ShadowAssemblyHelper(ShadowerOptions options)
     at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.Publicize.Shadower.ShadowAssemblyHelper(ShadowerOptions options)
     at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.Publicize.Shadower.ShadowAssembly(AppDomain domain, ShadowerOptions options)
     at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.Publicize.Shadower.ShadowAssembly(ShadowerOptions options)
     at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.BuildShadowReferences.BuildShadowTask.Execute()
     at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
     at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext()   Fm.Common.UnitTests         


  Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
  Error     The "BuildShadowTask" task failed unexpectedly.
  Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.Publicize.PublicizeException: Error occurred during processing of assembly 'D:\code\tsm\tdp\agents\mmc\Fm.Common\bin_816\Release\Fm.Common.dll': Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
     at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.Publicize.DynamicTypeEmitter.EmitAttachShadow()
     at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.Publicize.DynamicTypeEmitter..ctor(DynamicType type, ShadowerTargetType targetType)
     at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.Publicize.DynamicType..ctor(DynamicAssembly assembly, TypeBuilder outerType, Type type, TypeCreatorDelegate TypeCreator, ShadowerTargetType targetType)
     at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.Publicize.DynamicAssembly.ShadowType(Type type)
     at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.Publicize.Shadower.ShadowAssemblyHelper(ShadowerOptions options)
     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
     at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.Publicize.Shadower.ShadowAssemblyHelper(ShadowerOptions options)
     at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.Publicize.Shadower.ShadowAssemblyHelper(ShadowerOptions options)
     at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.Publicize.Shadower.ShadowAssembly(AppDomain domain, ShadowerOptions options)
     at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.Publicize.Shadower.ShadowAssembly(ShadowerOptions options)
     at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.BuildShadowReferences.BuildShadowTask.Execute()
     at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
     at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext()   Fm.Common.UnitTests
```

Comment: What's the structure of your project - does fm.common.unittest reference fm.common?  If so, check the framework target versions on both projects

Comment: Both projects target .NET Framework 4.5

Comment: Do you have a project reference, or a reference to the compiled library?

Comment: i have a reference to the dll

Comment: Have you tried referencing the project instead?  Apart from anything, it should make your dev / test pipeline easier to manage.

Comment: I gave up. I was trying to build using VS 2017 C# an unit test project that seems was VS 2010. I removed that old version unit test project and created a new VS 2017 unit test and did some code changes to call PrivateObject class etc. Eventually it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, problem was that there was a accessor file used. What is no more supportet by visual Stuio, so I removed it from the csproj file.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Shadow Include="Test References\Abc.xy.accessor" />
</ItemGroup>
```